# VSCode tunnel failed to connect to proxy: error connecting to tunnel: proxy connection failed: failed to lookup address information

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote, code-server, visual-studio-code-server

I am using VSCode CLI to create a tunnel behind a proxy:

`./code-insiders tunnel --verbose`

But it ends up with a connection error:

```
[2023-03-09 10:30:50] trace Found token in keyring
[2023-03-09 10:30:50] debug [reqwest::connect] starting new connection: https://api.github.com/
[2023-03-09 10:30:50] debug [reqwest::connect] proxy(http://my-proxy) intercepts 'https://api.github.com/'
[2023-03-09 10:30:50] debug [reqwest::connect] starting new connection: https://euw.rel.tunnels.api.visualstudio.com/
[2023-03-09 10:30:50] debug [reqwest::connect] proxy(http://my-proxy) intercepts 'https://euw.rel.tunnels.api.visualstudio.com/'
[2023-03-09 10:30:50] debug Starting tunnel to server...
[2023-03-09 10:30:50] trace Found token in keyring
[2023-03-09 10:30:51] debug [tunnels::connections::relay_tunnel_host] connecting via http_proxy on http://my-proxy:80
[2023-03-09 10:30:56] warn Error connecting to relay, will retry: error connecting to tunnel: proxy connection failed: failed to lookup address information: Try again
[2023-03-09 10:30:56] error Error connecting to tunnel endpoint: error connecting to tunnel: proxy connection failed: failed to lookup address information: Try again
```

OS: ubuntu 20.04

VSCode: 1.77.0 insiders

Does it mean my proxy does not permit remote tunnels? How can I confirm this?